# Server sent events in memory store of connection

Tags: spring-boot, server-sent-events

Experimented with server sent events and all the examples i saw is to store the connection in-memory, in this way spring can track the active connections and will keep the http connection open.

Is there an alternative of persisting this connections? This is due to the following reasons:

1. We are targeting 100 thousands of users, and keeping this number of connections might impact greatly on memory of the services.
2. When the application server crash, connection will not be impacted since they will be stored externally. I know this is not the right approach since connection is not meant to be keep long and should have a certain timeout applied.

Comment: Just a kind suggestion that it's not good a good practice to use long connections, which may cause a serious problem especially when your system is under attack.  You could use Websokcet instead for the interactive web application. And can also use a framework like STOMP to make it more easy and stable, like auto reconnection.

Comment: @Jaycee thanks for the suggestion, initially I'm looking at websockets + stomp but since the use case I have is only for one way communication between server and client, I'm thinking its expensive to keep ws connection. The beauty of SSE is i can control the connection and open or close when necessary